# WPF CommandParameter value from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

How to bind a variable from code behind to CommandParameter?

Snippet from WPF tree view MyTreeView.xaml:

```
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="save items" Command="CommandInMvvmModel" CommandParameter="ParameterInCodeBehind"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</TreeView.ContextMenu>
```

ParameterInCodeBehind is a variable in MyTreeView.xaml.cs

Comment: In case it is a public property of the MyTreeView class: `CommandParameter="{Binding ParameterInCodeBehind, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyTreeView}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Set CommandParameter from code behing via giving name of that MenuItem.

```
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem x:Name="menu" Header="save items" Command="CommandInMvvmModel" CommandParameter="ParameterInCodeBehind"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</TreeView.ContextMenu>
```

Code behind :

```
menu.CommandParameter = "value"
```